# Scatterplot from Pandas Dataframe Plotting Data against Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a Pandas DataFrame consisting of 20 columns with ~10k numeric values in each column. I can make a boxplot from this very easily showing something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0g1d.jpg . I would like to make a scatterplot version of this. The column number is actually the x coordinate for the data. (Technically it's off by one; it should go 1-20 rather than 0-19.) I can't seem to find an easy way to do this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply loop through all columns and plot one at a time:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create dummy dataframe
arr = np.random.rand(1000, 20)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

# Loop through columns and plot
for col in range(20):
    plt.scatter([col+1]*len(df), df.iloc[:, col], color='b')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!